# Switch Flutter's Xcode version

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have two Xcode on my system, Xcode 10.2 and Xcode 11. The default is on Xcode 10.2, how can make my Flutter use the Xcode 11?

Comment: did you find a way

Comment: check my answer and verify if it works on you too.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer.

sudo xcode-select -switch <path/to/>Xcode.app

example on terminal
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode11.app